# Jquery dropdown compatibility in IE 7

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

Here is the link that i faced the problem

Is not loading properly in the internet explorer IE7 but it is working fine IE 9.0 ,
![enter image description here][2]

What i am doing wrong anyone much appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6-8 do not support the `nav` element (which you're using for your navigation). This is causing your styles to not be applied to the elements associated with the `nav` element.

In order to add support for these elements you will need to download and insert the html5shiv!

Where do you insert the html5shiv? Insert it before you call your stylesheet.

Download the html5shiv here: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

**In your code Lines 4-6:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Homepage</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/html5shiv.js"></script>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Note: IE6-8 does not support any HTML5 elements such as `nav`, `header`, `article`, `aside`, `footer`, `figure`, etc.

Comment: @vignesh Your problem before was that you did not have the html5shiv so the browser would not render CSS for the `nav` element. Now you have to concentrate on making the navigation CSS cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @vignesh You're going to need to apply some IE-specific CSS. Take a look at: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/. Using Patrick O'Neill's method you can apply some IE-specific CSS and target only IE8 and less using html.lt-ie8 nav { /* IE styles here! */ } The problem is now that your CSS needs some modifications. Give it a try working it out!